# Date Picker not hiding

Tags: ios, datepicker

i have textfield and i have set the when the user click on that textfield the datepicker will display. But the problem is that the date picker is not hiding after. The below is my code.

```
- (IBAction) ac{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];


    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 0, 0)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    //datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    date.inputView = datePicker;

    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(LabelChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:datePicker];


}
- (void)LabelChange:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

}

-(IBAction)hidekey{

    [title resignFirstResponder];
    [date resignFirstResponder];
    [disc resignFirstResponder];
    [place resignFirstResponder];
    //datePicker.hidden = YES;
    [datePicker setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hiding remove it.

```
[datePicker removeFromSuperview];
```

**Another option**

Change your methods like:

```
- (IBAction) ac
{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                      [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    datePicker = nil;
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 0, 0)];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    //datePicker.hidden = NO;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    date.inputView = datePicker;

    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(LabelChange:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     [date setInputView:datePicker];

}

-(IBAction)hidekey
{

    [title resignFirstResponder];
    [date resignFirstResponder];
    [disc resignFirstResponder];
    [place resignFirstResponder];
    datePicker = nil;
}
```

Comment: it still have the same problem sir

Comment: @Nasir Check whether your hideKey method is calling

Comment: When the user click on background.

Comment: @Nasir: if that method works check whether data of datePicker is not nil inside it

Comment: date picker is hiding at first time but when keyboard is shown from the first textbox, and then i click on date textbox datepicker shown and then not hidden.

Comment: @Nasir: did you implemented any textfield delegates ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34487/discussion-between-nasir-and-midhun-mp)